# Crashing: "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS"?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, multithreading

I'm trying to clean up some of my code and replace long if statements with more complex functions. In this situation I want the variable "pickerSelectedName" to update two labels, but right now the function I created below crashes the program.

error code - Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0xbf784ffc)

Unfortunately I am still new to swift and Xcode, so I am not great with the debugger... I was wondering if someone could help explain why this is crashing?

**Person**

```
class Person {

    var name = String()
    var age = Int()

    let nameList:Dictionary = ["Bob":Bob(),"Joe":Joe(),"Tom":Tom()]

    class Bob:Person {
        override init() {
            super.init()
            name = "Bob"
            age = 27
        }
    }

    class Joe:Person {
        override init() {
            super.init()
            name = "Joe"
            age = 26
        }
    }

    class Tom:Person {
        override init() {
            super.init()
            name = "Tom"
            age = 28
        }
    }
}
```

**ViewController**

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ageLabel: UILabel!

    var pickerSelectedName = "Bob"

    var name = String()
    var age = String()

    override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        updateLabel(pickerSelectedName)
    }

    func updateLabel(name:String) {
        var selectedName = String()
        var selectedAge = String()
        if Person().nameList[name] != nil {
            selectedName = (Person().nameList[name]?.name)!
            selectedAge = (Person().nameList[name]?.name)!
        } else {
            selectedName = "Error"
            selectedAge = "Error"
        }
        nameLabel.text = selectedName
        ageLabel.text = selectedAge
    }
}
```

Comment: In your `viewWillAppear(animated: Bool)` method, I couldn't find where did you declare property `selectedName`. Did you omit some of your code, or did you make it intentionally?

Comment: Also `People` is not a viable class name, people tend to use singular nouns for class names since it is not a bag class. `Person` is the way to go.

Comment: oh, sorry... it should have been pickerSelectedName. I just updated, good find.

Comment: Could you please provide me the line it crashed?

Comment: If you click on the breakpoints navigator in Xcode (`cmd`+`7`) and click the little plus in the bottom left corner, you can add an exception breakpoint which will allow you to see where your code is crashing.

Comment: My guess is you didn't link your IBOutlets to the elements in the storyboard so they can't be loaded in, but I won't know for sure until you see what line is crashing

Comment: it crashes on line:    let nameList:Dictionary = ["Bob":Bob(),"Joe":Joe(),"Tom":Tom()]

Comment: cannot convert return expression of type '[String : People]' to return type 'Dictionary'

Comment: Well, you didn't explicitly initialized `Person` class. That may be the problem.

Comment: I said that because you are overriding init. I do not know Swift will override an implicitly defined initialization method.

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary stores associations between **keys of the same type** and **values of the same type** in a collection with no defined ordering.
First of all the following syntax is wrong with the above defination of dictionary.

```
 let nameList:Dictionary = ["Bob":Bob(),"Joe":Joe(),"Tom":Tom()]
```

Second thing please rework on the concepts of object oriented programming.Since you are declaring classes (Bob, Joe and Tom) as inner classes of People as well as sub-classes of People. Please do one thing at a time.

Comment: would you mind going into a bit more detail? the dictionary contains keys of type String and values of type Person correct?